# Как задать текущую дату в форме?

Tags: reactjs, дата, jsx

Как можно указать сегодняшнюю дату в форме?

```
function App() {
  let [date, setDate] = useState('')

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div className={'red'} id={'red'}></div>
        <input value={date}  onChange={e => setDate(e.target.value)} id="date"  className={'date'} type="date"  />

    </div>

  );
}
```

Comment: и куда это я впишу

Comment: Стейт лучше объявлять через `const` чтобы избегать очевидных ошибок

Comment: И посмотрите [useRef](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef) возможно вам не нужен `useState`. [Будет полезно почитать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56455887/react-usestate-or-useref)

Answer (score 1):

Что бы задать текущую дату для input, потребуется создать объект Date, взять год, месяц и число. Месяц и число проверить на длину и если 1, то добавить лидирующий 0.

Все это лучше делать в useState при создании компонента

```
function App() {
  let [date, setDate] = useState(() => {
    const date = new Date(); // Создаем дату
    const month = (date.getMonth()+1).toString(); // Получаем месяц
    const day = date.getDate().toString(); // Получаем день
    // Возвращаем строку формата даты для input type=date
    return `${date.getFullYear()}-${month.length === 2 ? month : `0${month}` }-${day.length === 2 ? day : `0${day}`}`
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className={'red'} id={'red'}></div>
      <input value={date} onChange={e => setDate(e.target.value)} id="date" className={'date'} type="date"  />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Вместо проверок можно использовать [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Comment: @EzioMercer о, я что то новенькое для себя открыл или забыл уже про это...